# Need to print all string

Tags: c

I have a string with multiple \0's and I need to output the whole string.
`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char *arr = "asdf\0\0zxcvb\0"; // for example
    for (int i = 0; arr[i]; i++) {
      printf("%c", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`
Help me come up with a solution.

I have no idea what should I do.

Comment: Why do you want to do it like this? What is the actual problem?

Comment: ```asdf\0\0zxcvb\0```  ----> 
 ```asdf\\0\\0zxcvb\\0```

Comment: Use ```strlen``` to compute the length of the string, and then test against it in the loop.

Comment: @kiner_shah, Such is the task.

Comment: @Haris `strlen` will stop at the first `\0` occurence.

Comment: Not after you embed an extra escape sequence.

Comment: @Haris Yeah but that's not the point here, in this example he only showed a mere string, but what if he wanted to parse a raw binary and such ? we can't always edit the string.

Comment: @AlexeiMihaylenko If this is a homework task I'm sure there is some important information in the task description that you haven't posted here... With the information in the question the only answer is: Not possible

Comment: @SupportUkraine I have to copy the text from the file and put it into a dynamic array of strings and then output

Comment: @AlexeiMihaylenko hmmm..... sounds like a completely different task!! Why do the question have a pointer to a const char array with embedded `\0` ? That's not what you normally get from reading from a file. What does the file contain? Is it a text file or a binary file?

Comment: @SupportUkraine, Because in the end such a line turns out, which needs to be output. Text file.

Comment: @Paul-Marie Exactly why. He showed us a string literal here, not raw binary. But now he mentions that he needs to read from a file, unlike his original query.

Comment: @AlexeiMihaylenko Sounds strange but without knowing what kind of file it is and without knowing how you read from the file, it's impossible to say. My advice is that you post another question where you described what you are actually doing and post the code that you are using for reading and the content of the file, etc... The way you have written this question hides important information. However, due to the answers already posted, it's not good to edit this question... it's better to ask a new

Comment: [A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1p1). `"asdf\0\0zxcvb\0"` is an array of characters and a string literal, but is **not** a string.

Comment: @SupportUkraine And what will change if the array is dynamic? I need to know how  to output this line, why do you need to know how I input it? The final line may be the same as in the example.

Comment: "I need to know how to output this line" When your needs clash with reality, reality wins. Sorry about that.

Comment: @AlexeiMihaylenko The function call that you use for reading from the file may tell you stuff like the number of characters read... if so the problem can be solved.... but it's impossible for me to tell when I can't see the actual code.... I can tell for sure that your actual code is not using a string literal (aka const char array) and that makes a big difference...

Comment: Unless you define some other terminating condition, or supply extra information, (eg. the length of the char array), it is not possible for any software to detect the end of data pointed to.

Comment: Alexei Mihaylenko, Too bad, just about to post answer for [What was the last character printed to the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75105060/what-was-the-last-character-printed-to-the-console).  Oh well, night-night.

Answer (score 3):

This code

```
char *arr = "asdf\0\0zxcvb\0";
```

gives you a pointer to a string literal (aka a const char array).

When you only have a pointer, there is no way to get the size of the whole array when it contains `\0` in the middle. The "normal" way would be to use `strlen(arr)` but that won't work for this case as it will stop at the first `\0`.

Consequently it is impossible to print it as an unknow number of traditional zero-terminated strings. The problem is that you can't know when to stop.

For something like that to work, you'll need extra information (e.g. array size or total number of strings in the array) or have some special rules (e.g. a sentinel value to indicate end-of-array).

Comment: Also, `char *` should really be `const char *` since a string literal is not modifiable.

Comment: All lines except the last one end in \n, so I don't know what to do with this last line

Comment: @AlexeiMihaylenko I don't understand your comment... The const char array in your code does not have any `\n`

Answer (score 1):

This will print out the entire string and not stop at the null characters. As it continues until `i` is equal to or greater than the sizeof `arr`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char arr[] = "asdf\0\0zxcvb\0"; // for example
  int i = 0;
  while (i < sizeof(arr)) {
    printf("%c", arr[i]);
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
asdfzxcvb
```

Alternatively you could also use `fwrite`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char arr[] = "asdf\0\0zxcvb\0"; // for example
  int len = sizeof(arr);
  fwrite(arr, 1, len, stdout);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But what the difference between *arr and arr[]?

Comment: @AlexeiMihaylenko `char *arr` is **a pointer to a char** while `char arr[] = "...";` is **a char array**. Two very different things.... The important thing for this code is that `sizeof` returns different values in the two cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can't print it entirely, unless you know it's actual size.

If one (or multiples) `\0` lay in your string, you can't use it to know where string's end belong. Your only way is to know the string's total size like:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  printf("%c", arr[i]);
}
```

This method is used while displaying raw binary, who often have multiple `\0` occurrence in their content, but total binary size is known so it's not much a problem.

Another way of handling this is to use C++ and `std::vector` type, which can be used as string, but with a `length` property so you can easily have multiple `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the above answers, there's no possible way to compute the size of an array of characters with embedded null characters with only a pointer.

But if you do have the size, you could get hacky:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
   const char *arr = "asdf\0\0zxcvb\0"; 
   for (size_t i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == 0) {
            printf("\\0");
        } else {
         printf("%c", arr[i]);
        }
   }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Sample Output:

```
asdf\0\0zxcvb\0
```

Or perhaps:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
   /* Escape the null bytes */
   const char *arr = "asdf\\0\\0zxcvb\\0"; 
   size_t len = strlen(arr);

   for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
        printf("%c", arr[i]); 
   }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Sample Output:

```
asdf\0\0zxcvb\0
```